# How to count rows with conditional after grouping in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
dat <- read_csv(
  "s1,s2,v1,v2
   a,b,10,20
   a,b,22,NA
   a,b,13,33
   c,d,3,NA
   c,d,4.5,NA
   c,d,10,20"
)

dat
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>      s1    s2    v1    v2
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     a     b  10.0    20
#> 2     a     b  22.0    NA
#> 3     a     b  13.0    33
#> 4     c     d   3.0    NA
#> 5     c     d   4.5    NA
#> 6     c     d  10.0    20
```

What I want to do is

1. Filter row based on `v1` values
2. Group by `s1` and `s2`
3. Count total lines in every group
4. Count lines in every group where `v2` is not `NA`.

For example with `v1_filter >= 0` we get this:

```
s1 s2 total_line non_na_line
a  b     3          2
c  d     3          1
```

And with `v1_filter >= 10` we get this:

```
s1 s2 total_line non_na_line
a  b     2          1
c  d     1          1
```

How can I achieve that with data.table or dplyr?
In reality we have around ~31M rows in `dat`. So we need
a fast method.

I'm stuck with this

```
 library(data.table)
 dat <- data.table(dat)

 v1_filter = 0
 dat[, v1 >= v1_filter, 
     by=list(s1,s2)]
```

Comment: This feels like it needs an example of what you've already tried and what went wrong, else it risks being a 'do my work' question. Expanding on `dat %>% group_by(s1, s2) %>% count()` is a simple dplyr answer, but I don't know how performant it is.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll Thanks but your dplyr doesn't give count for `non_na_line`

Comment: DT[i,j,k] in data table stands for i for selection, j for operation , k for grouping. You have put selection in the second place , actually it should be first place, and second place should be count (.N)

Comment: @SymbolixAU Thanks for pointing out. I modified to `>=10` in my OP.

Comment: @neversaint that's where the 'expanding on' comment is relevant. `dat %>% group_by(s1, s2) %>% filter(!is.na(v2)) %>% count()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> library(readr)
> dat <- read_csv(
+   "s1,s2,v1,v2
+    a,b,10,20
+    a,b,22,NA
+    a,b,13,33
+    c,d,3,NA
+    c,d,4.5,NA
+    c,d,10,20"
+ )
> 
> dat
# A tibble: 6 x 4
     s1    s2    v1    v2
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <int>
1     a     b  10.0    20
2     a     b  22.0    NA
3     a     b  13.0    33
4     c     d   3.0    NA
5     c     d   4.5    NA
6     c     d  10.0    20
```

Using data.table since you have a big data

```
> library(data.table)
data.table 1.10.4
  The fastest way to learn (by data.table authors): https://www.datacamp.com/courses/data-analysis-the-data-table-way
  Documentation: ?data.table, example(data.table) and browseVignettes("data.table")
  Release notes, videos and slides: http://r-datatable.com
> dat=data.table(dat)
```

Without removing NA and keeping V1 filter as 0.1

```
> dat1=dat[v1>0.1,.N,.(s1,s2)]
> dat1
   s1 s2 N
1:  a  b 3
2:  c  d 3
```

Removing v2 NA and keeping V1 filter as 0.1

```
> dat2=dat[v1>0.1&is.na(v2)==F,.N,.(s1,s2)]
> dat2
   s1 s2 N
1:  a  b 2
2:  c  d 1
```

Merging the two and keeping V1 filter as 0

```
 > dat[v1 > 0, .N, by = .(s1, s2)][ dat[v1 > 0 & !is.na(v2), .N, by = .(s1, s2)] , on = c("s1", "s2") , nomatch = 0 ]
       s1 s2 N i.N
    1:  a  b 3   2
    2:  c  d 3   1
```

Comment: thanks. How can I modify your code so that the output has the form as in my OP?

Comment: @neversaint join the last two statements `dat[v1 > 0, .N, by = .(s1, s2)][
 dat[v1 > 0 & !is.na(v2), .N, by = .(s1, s2)]
 , on = c("s1", "s2")
 , nomatch = 0
 ]`

Answer (score 4):

Using `sum` should help. Operating on a logical vector, it treats each `TRUE` as `1` and `FALSE` as `0`, so you can easily do this:

```
dat %>%
    group_by(s1, s2) %>%
    summarise(total_lines = n(),
              non_na_line = sum(!is.na(v2)))

# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   s1 [?]
     s1    s2 total_lines non_na_line
  <chr> <chr>       <int>       <int>
1     a     b           3           2
2     c     d           3           1
```

You'll easily be able to add in a filter between `group_by` and `summarise`, to get what you want. Keep in mind that `summarise` will only retain columns that you group by.

## Benchmark

For what it's worth, I ran a quick benchmark, with some test data of similar size as yours.

```
s1charMix <- rep(letters[seq(from = 1, to = 10)], length.out = 30000000)
s2charMix <- rep(letters[seq(from = 11, to = 20)], length.out = 30000000)
s1chars <- sample(s1charMix, 30000000)
s2chars <- sample(s2charMix, 30000000)
v1Nums <- runif(30000000, min = 0, max = 20)
nomissing <- sample(1:200000,1)
int.mix <- rbinom(30000000 - nomissing, 30, 0.3)
nalist <- rep(NA, nomissing)
v2NumsNA <- sample(x = c(int.mix, nalist), 30000000)
df <- data_frame(s1 = s1chars, s2 = s2chars, v1 = v1Nums, v2 = v2NumsNA)
```

This should roughly replicate the size and type of the data you suggest:

```
df

# A tibble: 30,000,000 x 4
      s1    s2         v1    v2
   <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <int>
 1     d     s  9.2123603     7
 2     b     q 16.6638639    11
 3     g     o 18.3682028    11
 4     g     s  0.8779067     9
 5     a     s  0.0719127    10
 6     b     q 16.8809193    12
 7     h     q 15.4382455     6
 8     e     k  2.3565489    11
 9     h     p 16.4508811     9
10     d     n  2.7283823    11
# ... with 29,999,990 more rows

df %>%
    filter(is.na(v2))

# A tibble: 116,924 x 4
      s1    s2         v1    v2
   <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <int>
 1     d     r 13.1448988    NA
 2     b     o  0.2703848    NA
 3     b     t 18.8319385    NA
 4     a     s 11.6448437    NA
 5     j     m  0.5388760    NA
 6     i     k  8.7098427    NA
 7     d     s  6.1149735    NA
 8     h     p  2.5552694    NA
 9     g     r  0.9057442    NA
10     b     s 19.8886830    NA
# ... with 116,914 more rows
```

Now, let's benchmark `dplyr` operations vs `data.table`:

```
### dplyr
df %>%
    filter(v1 > 10) %>%
    group_by(s1, s2) %>%
    summarise(total_lines = n(),
              non_na_line = sum(!is.na(v2)))

# A tibble: 100 x 4
# Groups:   s1 [?]
      s1    s2 total_lines non_na_line
   <chr> <chr>       <int>       <int>
 1     a     k      150327      149734
 2     a     l      149655      149062
 3     a     m      149794      149200
 4     a     n      149771      149197
 5     a     o      149495      148942
...
> system.time(df %>% filter(v1 > 10) %>% group_by(s1, s2) %>% summarise(total_lines = n(), non_na_line = sum(!is.na(v2))))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.848   0.420   2.290
> system.time(for (i in 1:100) df %>% filter(v1 > 10) %>% group_by(s1, s2) %>% summarise(total_lines = n(), non_na_line = sum(!is.na(v2))))
   user  system elapsed 
187.657  55.878 245.528 

### Data.table
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(df)
> dat[v1 > 10, .N, by = .(s1, s2)][dat[v1 > 10 & !is.na(v2), .N, by = .(s1, s2)] , on = c("s1", "s2") , nomatch = 0]
 s1 s2      N    i.N
  1:  b  q 149968 149348
  2:  g  o 150411 149831
  3:  h  q 150132 149563
  4:  h  p 150786 150224
  5:  e  o 149951 149353
 ...
> system.time(dat[v1 > 10, .N, by = .(s1, s2)][dat[v1 > 10 & !is.na(v2), .N, by = .(s1, s2)] , on = c("s1", "s2") , nomatch = 0])
   user  system elapsed 
  2.027   0.228   2.271
> system.time(for (i in 1:100) dat[v1 > 10, .N, by = .(s1, s2)][dat[v1 > 10 & !is.na(v2), .N, by = .(s1, s2)] , on = c("s1", "s2") , nomatch = 0])
   user  system elapsed 
213.281  43.949 261.664
```

**TL;DR** `dplyr` and `data.table` are similarly fast, if anything `dplyr` is slightly faster